# How to get the user name if I have user_id field in a joined table in a blade

Tags: php, laravel

The user_id field below exists in the Grpusr table. I want to display the user name (i.e. first_name) which exists in the users table instead of the user_id as shown below. How can I do this conversion in a blade?

```
@if(!empty($jreq))
         <p>{{$jreq->user_id}} is requesting to join {{$jreq->name}} group</p>
```

Comment: could you show your query or your table structure?

Comment: Show your table structure and relationship ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your response `$jreq` what you are getting ?

then if you already joined your tables simply you can use

Ex :

```
$jreq = Grpusr::join('users','grpusrs.user_id','=','users.id')->first();
    {{ $jreq->first_name }}
```

or you can use relationship like this [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

```
class Grpusr extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user that owns the phone.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

then you can use

```
{{ $jreq->user->first_name }}
```